# It seems I am king in your human life

Tags: riddle

```
You eat food? It is me.
You play soccer? It is me.
You give birth? It is me.
You go to work? it is me.
You do sex? It is me.
You work? It is me (over 99% of times).
You solve a crossword? It is me.
You use a pistol? It is me.
You use a sniper? That's me...but one of the annoying corrections, that's not me.
You use a weak bomb? It is me.
You use a strong bomb? It is not me.
You dropped your pencil? It is not me.
```

Well, OK, by mentioning your "abstract" actions, maybe the others are cooperating as well. But surely, when you think of the more specific tasks (eg kicking the ball in soccer), I am more prevalent.

Tip:

> The answer is a scientific concept

(I hope I don't initiate a philosophical discussion here ;) )

Comment: I am between 'brain' and 'eye' as answer.

Comment: It is a natural concept, and it is not a body part.

Comment: The line "You use a sniper?" Do you mean "hire a sniper" or "use a sniper rifle"? Also, can you be more specific about what counts as a weak/strong bomb?

Comment: Is the last line a part of the puzzle??

Comment: @Lakshay Sura no

Comment: @hexomino 1) Both actually would still be the same 2) If you figure the difference in the underlying mechanism (stressing underlying VERY much here) between weak (=most) bombs and (REALLY) strong bombs, you'll have solved this

Comment: Is it rot 13(Svffvba naq Shfvba)??

Comment: @Lakshay Sura Yes....what's behind them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer might be

> Electromagnetism

Reasoning

> Of the four fundamental forces (gravity, electromagnetism, strong and weak interactions) electromagnetism plays a dominant role in all of the activities listed. Generally, kinetic interactions between two bodies will be electromagnetic in nature. For example, kicking a football involves the electromagnetic interaction between the molecules in your football boot and the molecules of the ball.
>  As for the exceptions, the minor correction for the sniper is probably gravity (long range shooting), when dropping your pencil gravity is the dominant force. Finally, the "strong" bomb might be referring to thermonuclear weapons which use a fusion reaction and the weak interaction is the dominant force here.

Comment: @hexonimo It would be great if you can explain how does electromagnetism work in all of these since I can't find a link of lot of these from electromagnetism.

Comment: @LakshaySura I've added a line here to try to explain. Generally, whenever two bodies collide there is a significant electromagnetic interaction. When you kick a football the interaction that makes the football move is electromagnetic in nature. Perhaps, you normally don't think about it this way? I'll grant you the answer is a little unsatisfying as gravity plays a reasonable role in many of these activities too.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is

> Striker

although I can't review it on all the clues. If this is, in fact, the right answer, could you help me relate it to the least obvious clues?

Here is why:

```
You play soccer? It is me.
```

> A striker is a player on a football (soccer) team who plays nearest to the opposing team's.

```
You go to work? it is me.
You work? It is me (over 99% of times).
```

> A striker is an employee on strike, who's go to work every time but only works 99%(ish) of the times (because on 1% he/she is on strike).

```
You use a pistol? It is me.
```

> A striker is a person with a weapon (like a pistol) ready to attack.

The other clues are less obvious to me (please don't judge me; english is not my native language).

Comment: Can you expound on why you think this is the answer? Can you explain which relationships you have identified and why?

Comment: @DanielC, it's done. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Sorry, not the intended answer. Added a tip.

Comment: No harm to try and strike the problem though... :)

Answer (score 0):

> Perhaps it is chemical energy. Dropping a pencil is only potential energy

Comment: Your answer is still a subset of the answer.

Comment: Howdy, and welcome to PSE! When answering a riddle here, typically one is expected to explain how every line contributes to the answer. As the OP indicates, your answer bears on the question, so adding more details will help you engage better with the question.